# What is the order of the subgroup of G (rubiks cube group) generated by <FF,RR>?

Tags: abstract-algebra, rubiks-cube

I got:

=1,FF,RR,FFRR,RRFF

But in my text book the answer is 12? Does any one else know the other elements?

I assumed since FFFFRRRR=1 there were no more?

Comment: What about FFRRFFRR? This is not FFFFRRRR.

Comment: Ahhhh yes... seems obvious now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f=FF$ and $g=RR$. Note that $f$ and $g$ have order $2$, and $fg$ and $gf$ have order $6$, i.e., we have $(fg)^6=e$ and no smaller power of it. This still is not enough to show that the group generated by $f$ and $g$ has order $12$. We also have
$$
g(fg)^2=(fg)^3f.
$$
So the $12$ elements are
$$
e,f,fg,(fg)f,(fg)^2,(fg)^2f,g,gf,(gf)g,(gf)^2,(gf)^2g,(gf)^3=(fg)^3.
$$

Comment: I needed to write out the elements rather than a proof the order is 12. Just struggling to see what the other elements would be.

Answer (score 0):

using $f=FF$ and $g=RR$ (borrowing from @dietrich) isn't the answer just:
$$
e,f,fg,fgf,(fg)^2,(fg)^2f,(fg)^3,(fg)^3f,(fg)^4,(fg)^4f,(fg)^5,(fg)^5f
$$

and then $(fg)^6=e$?

Comment: But what about gf? Would this not be an element?

Comment: same as $(fg)^5$